# Multprocessing, global variable not being updated

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am attempting to use multiprocessing to fill a dictionary which I will then run some data analytics on.  However, I can't figure out how/why my processes won't add values to the global list object.  Here is my test code

```
this_list = {}


def run_this(x, y):
    global this_list
    this_list[x] = y


def main():
    global this_list
    p1 = mp.Process(target=run_this, args=(0, 3))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=run_this, args=(1, 4))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=run_this, args=(2, 5))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    print(this_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need a form of IPC as all these are separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared memory for "global" variables. Example from [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

Comment: Thanks, I really need a dictionary though(Using unique string keys).  I couldn't seem to find a dictionary in the multiprocessing module though.  Anyway around this?

Comment: You always can represent dict as array. Actually dict is too complex and python-specific structure.